# How to deal with URLBlockedUncategorized when trying to connect with kubeconfig file?

Tags: ubuntu, minikube, kubeconfig, telepresence

I´m currently working on ubuntu linux. I have already implemented minikube and have a config for kubernetes ready:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/<user>/.minikube/ca.crt
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Wed, 11 Oct 2023 11:58:40 CEST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.31.2
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://192.168.49.2:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Wed, 11 Oct 2023 11:58:40 CEST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.31.2
      name: context_info
    namespace: default
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/<user>/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /home/<user>/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key
```

I'm trying to connect with my kubernetes configuration with this command:

```
telepresence --kubeconfig=/home/<user>/.kube/config connect
```

But then I get this:

```
telepresence connect: error: connector.Connect: initial cluster check failed: Get "https://192.168.49.2:8443/version": URLBlockedUncategorized
```

I don't know what exactly "URLBlockedUncategorized" means and I can't really find an explanation in relation to telepresence. Is it blocked by the corporate proxy? Do I have to edit some certificate in minikube? Is there a command to deactivate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials and errors, it somehow worked once I wrote

```
telepresence quit -s
```

and then

```
telepresence connect
```

I don't believe this was the main solution to the problem, so I write what else I did before that:

- Added minikube ip address to the "no_proxy" and "NO_PROXY" environment variables.
- Once used this command:

  telepresence helm install --never-proxy=

I also recently understood how the global configuration described [here](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/telepresence/latest/reference/config) works: You need to create that yaml-file yourself and then do the following:

```
telepresence helm install -f <path to>/<your-global-config.yaml>
```

Don't copy paste the global-config one-to-one. You have to check the registry as well as add the minikube subnet below the "neverProxySubnets".